# How do I install Diskdigger on ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

DiskDigger is not in Ubuntu software. How do I install this?

Comment: The correct spelling for the application name is DiskDigger, one word.

Comment: https://www.diskdigger.org/linux

Answer (score 1):

First, install the packages for Windows Forms 4.0 for Mono:

```
sudo apt-get install libmono-system-windows-forms4* libmono-system-design*
```

Next, download DiskDigger and unzip it:

```
wget http://diskdigger.org/diskdigger.zip
unzip diskdigger.zip
```

Run DiskDigger (your current directory must be the one containing DiskDigger.exe, otherwise you have to specify the path):

```
sudo mono DiskDigger.exe
```