# How do I remove diskdigger completely from my computer?

Tags: software-uninstall

I don't want to have any trace of diskdigger on my computer. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @DKBose https://askubuntu.com/q/1052570/367990

Answer (score 2):

Enter the following commands to completely delete DiskDigger and everything asociated from it's install, based on, and as per [Running DiskDigger in Linux](https://www.diskdigger.org/linux). The 1st part completely removes (purges) the packages for Windows Forms 4.0 for Mono you needed to run it.

```
sudo apt-get purge libmono-system-windows-forms4* libmono-system-design*
sudo apt autoremove
rm diskdigger.zip
rm DiskDigger.exe
```